# D3 force layout nodes attributes not updated properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have network data for different days which I plot as a force-directed graph for each single day. When I press a button, the network is partially (leaving nodes are removed, new nodes are drawn) updated to the following day. Everything is working fine except for one thing.

For every new day I update some attributes of my nodes-array from my data (e.g. degree of the node). This also works fine, since I can see that the attributes have been updated correctly when I just look at my nodes-array after switching to the next day. However the command

```
     `.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) { return 2*d.Degree+10; })`
```

is not conducted with the new attributes and the radius of the nodes do not represent by the degree of the node at the date the graph show.

How can I update my graph such that the new values for Degree are used to define the radius of the nodes?

Here is my function start(), which I call after manipulating my data to plot the graph:

```
function start() {

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-130)
    .linkDistance(230)
    .size([width, height]);

force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(edges)

linkOP = linkOP.data(edges, function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
linkOP.enter().insert("line", ".node1")
    .attr("class", "link1")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return 2*d.weight.weight;
      });
linkOP.exit()
    .remove();

nodeOP = nodeOP.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});
nodeOP.enter()  
    .append("g")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r",   function(d) { return 2*d.Degree+10; })
    .attr("class", "node")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.bipartite); });

nodeOP.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.name; });
nodeOP.call(force.drag);
nodeOP.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
nodeOP.moveToFront();
nodeOP.exit().remove();

force.start();

clean();

force.on("tick", function() {
    linkOP.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodeOP.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    nodeOP.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

});

}
```

I know this is a very simple question... Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't have an update to the radius. Everything called by .enter() only occur for new items. So because you only have the line

```
.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) { return 2*d.Degree+10; })`
```

Inside the .enter that portion only occurs on the new nodes.

I built a jsfiddle on enter, update, exit. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheMcMurder/H3HTe/

I hope that helps

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the quick respond. According to your example I added: 'var node_array = svg1.selectAll("circle").data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});
  node_array.attr("r", function(d) { return 2*d.Degree+10; });' before the line: 'nodeOP = nodeOP.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});' in my start function. Now I see that the size of not updated nodes is changing but still not such that they respresent the attributes assigened to them. This is strange to me since when I look at nodeOP-array in the browser all the attributes are defined correctly.

Comment: Found my mistake! Thank's a lot dawg and have a great weekend (u really murdered that problem, which quite fits ur name!). Stackoverflow rules!